# SetWindowsHookEx doesn't work without a MessageBox call

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

I'm following this article http://kylehalladay.com/blog/2020/05/20/Hooking-Input-Snake-In-Notepad.html up to section "Writing a Simple Hook Payload".

I use the code https://github.com/khalladay/render-with-notepad/tree/master/Render-With-Notepad/Inject_Payload_DisableKeyInput as my base.

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>

#include "inject_payload_disablekeyinput.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return 1;
}

HHOOK hhk; // This is our hook handle

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: {
        hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, hinstDLL, 0);
        //MessageBox(NULL, "DLL loaded", "Woohoo", 0); //Line A
        break;
    }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
$ LoadLibrary_Injector.exe  notepad.exe "F:\render-with-notepad\Render-With-Notepad\x64\Debug\Inject_Payload_DisableKeyInput.dll"
PID Found: 13660
Success! remote thread started in process 13660
```

My notepad can still show every key I pressed. The KeyboardProc hook doesn't seem to work.

However, if I uncomment Line A, my KeyboardProc function now hooks every process.

**Warning, if you want to try my code, you may have to sign out your Windows account or reboot your machine in order to remove the hooking effect.**

Why does `MessageBox()` make a difference?

Comment: The answer is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)#remarks): *"This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**"*

Comment: Alternatively there are [very strict rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) about what you can run in DllMain. These include things like calls to anything in `User32.dll` of which `MessageBox` is one.

Comment: @IInspectable I roughly get the idea, but can you elaborate more? I'm not an expert in C++/WinAPI. How does `MessageBox()` install a message loop? What other functions can install a message loop? If LoadLibrary_Injector.exe is a GUI application, it comes with a message loop, right?

Comment: *"How does `MessageBox()` install a message loop?"* - A message loop is a concept, not a thing you can install. It's a regular loop that continuously reads messages from the calling thread's message queue, and dispatches them to their respective recipients. Message queues are per-thread, and any thread that needs to dispatch messages needs a message loop. *"I'm not an expert in C++/WinAPI."* - That's going to make for a frustrating experience. As an example, the blocking call to `MessageBox` from `DllMain` has just paved the road for an instant deadlock of every thread in the entire system.

Comment: As @IInspectable said, message loop is a concept, you can't install it and the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Anyway, forget the message loop. Just make my code work and conform whatever best practice.